# Trouble converting a modulus pow() function from Lua to Python

Tags: python, lua, pow, modulo

I have tried to rewrite a Lua mod_pow() function ( which works ) to Python. The syntax and everything looks ok to me so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Does anyone know what I need to change in my Python code to get it to work and give 81 as the answer as the Lua code does?

Lua working code:

```
function modPow(b,e,m)
        if m == 1 then
                return 0
        else
                local r = 1
                b = b % m
                while e > 0 do
                        if e % 2 == 1 then
                                r = (r*b) % m
                        end
                        e = e >> 1     --use 'e = math.floor(e / 2)' on Lua 5.2 or older
                        b = (b^2) % m
                end
                return r
        end
end

modPow(7,4,145)
81.0
```

Python non working code:

```
def modular_pow(b, e, m):
    if m == 1: 
       return 0
    else:
      r=1
      b = b % m
      while e > 0:
        if e % 2 == 1:
           r = (r*b) % m
        e = e >> 1
        b = (b^2)% m
    return r

modular_pow(7,4,145)
7
```

Comment: `b^2` should be `b**2`

Comment: `^` is XOR in Python.

Comment: Barmar, if you post that as an answer, i'll give you credit for answering my question, this works.

Comment: Small note on efficiency: you should try exponentiation by squaring, it's usually much faster for large exponents :)

Comment: I didn't think this was worth answering, I voted to close it as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is bitwise XOR in python. reference: [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_XOR.html)